# Validación de formularios con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Por que no valida mi formulario?, quiero que me salga un alert si no escribo nada pero no sale nada :(

```
function mandar(){

var nombre = document.getElementByName('nombre').value;
if (nombre=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}

var apellidoP = document.getElementByName('apPaterno').value;
if (apellidoP=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var apellidoM = document.getElementByName('amPaterno').value;
if (apellidoM=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var caminando = document.getElementByName('Caminando').value;
if (caminando=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var Bicicleta = document.getElementByName('Bicicleta').value;
if (Bicicleta=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var Camion = document.getElementByName('Camion').value;
if (Camion=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var Carro = document.getElementByName('Carro').value;
if (Carro=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var Raite = document.getElementByName('Raite').value;
if (Raite=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var Sexo = document.getElementByName('sexo').value;
if (Sexo=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var semestre = document.getElementByName('semestre').value;
if (semestre=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var vespertino = document.getElementByName('Vespertino').value;
if (vespertino=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}
var matutino = document.getElementByName('Matutino').value;
if (matutino=null) {
    alert("Introduce tus datos por favor :(");
}



document.getElementById('formulario').submit();
}
```

Comment: ayudaría mucho si pusieras tu html para descartar un error en su estructura

Answer (score 1):

si usas un solo = estas asignando un valor

```
if (nombre=null) {
```

hace que nombre valga null

---

```
 if (nombre == null) {
```

compara nombre y null

para saber si un input está vacio:

```
var nombre = document.getElementsByName('nombre')[0].value;
if (nombre == null || nombre == "") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema viene es que en el if no estas comparando si no asignando un valor, al usar solo un signo igual:

```
if (nombre=null)
```

Prueba de esta manera

```
if (nombre === undefined && nombre === "")
```

Comment: Al usar si es igual `undefined` ya tomaria en cuenta ese caso o quizas deberia evaluar tambien si es igual a `null`